# Get frame from video in Java

Tags: java, image, video

I need to extract a single frame from a video file to use as a thumbnail. I would like to be able to generate thumbnails from most common video formats and would also like to be cross platform, so a pure Java solution is preferential.

It would be also useful to be able to get additional information about the video such as frame rate and total length so I can get a frame from a specific place in the file.

I have looked at Xuggler but it appears to be depreciated.

Comment: Can you please leave a comment when you downvote, I would like to know why.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to do this server side, then it may be easiest to leverage ffmpeg as it is commonly used for this type of video manipulation and it also has a large user community.

As ffmpeg is C based, using it with Java requires some sort of wrapper or JNI approach so it is not strictly speaking pure Java, but it is common to use it this way in Java programs. An example wrapper library, which seems to be regularly maintained, is:

- https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper

Comment: Using FFmpeg with a wrapper like this seems to be fairly simple, however it means I have to distribute FFmpeg for all major platforms I plan to run on, so I cannot use this method due to application size constraints. (FFmpeg and FFprobe are over 60MB combined just for Windows)

Comment: Sounds like something odd there - I have seen much smaller (<10M) with apps using ffmpeg wrapper for Android, and that includes the whole Android app also.